# How to show widget sent from another page based on a condition in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

I have a page that I use in common. I'm posting a "widget" named "custom widget" on this page. If "custom widget" is sent I want to show it. If it's not sent, don't do anything. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use your custom widget like this:

```dart
customWidget != null ? Row(children: [customWidget!]) : Container()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the customWidget is null and show it if it's not.

```
customWidget ?? Container()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `if` condition like below.

```
Row(
  children: [
    if (customWidget != null) customWidget,
  ],
),
```